# Why are implicit property names not allowed in an array of anonymous types?

Tags: c#, anonymous-types

Why isn't this allowed?

```
int A = 5, B = 10, X = 5, Y = 5;
var array = new[] { new { A, B }, new { X, Y } };
```

When I try to compile, I get:

> CS0826: No best type found for implicitly-typed array

Feels a bit counter-intuitive, because with a regular anonymous type I can do this:

```
int X = 5, Y = 5;
var point = new { X, Y };
```

Comment: It is allowed, so long as the property names are the same. Otherwise you're creating an array of different anonymous types that would have to be cast down to object, and I have no idea how you would plan to go about using that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You *can* do this, although I don't know that you *should*.

```
int A = 5, B = 10, X = 5, Y = 5;
var array = new object[] { new { A, B }, new { X, Y } };
```

This is valid, and will compile just fine, and be very, very difficult to use. I strongly recommend against doing this.

As for the reason why using the implicit initialization syntax doesn't work, 12.6 of the spec has this to say about array initializers:

> For a single-dimensional array, the array initializer must consist of a sequence of expressions that are **assignment compatible with the element type of the array**. The expressions initialize array elements in increasing order, starting with the element at index zero.

(emphasis mine)

So there isn't a compatible type between your two anonymous types as, well, they are anonymous.

Comment: Thanks for adding that documentation quote, now I understand the problem was the inconsistent property names.

Answer (score 7):

You will either need to specify the names of the properties in your anonymous types implicitly, or use an array of object

```
var array = new[] { new { val1= A, val2=B }, new { val1=X, val2=Y } };
```

or

```
var array = new object [] { new { A, B }, new { X, Y } };
```

However lets take this a step further and use Tuples yehaa, shorter syntax, typed, and more succinct

```
var array = new[] { (A, B), (X, Y) };
```

or named tuples, best of all worlds

```
var array = new (int something ,int another)[] { (A, B), (X, Y) };
```

Answer (score 3):

Or one more case (in addition to the other answers):

```
int A = 5, B = 10, X = 5, Y = 5;
var array = new[] { new { A, B }, new { A=X, B=Y } };
```

In this case you are creating an array of implicitly typed object, each of which has two integer properties, one named A, the other named B.